# Insert Iframe to a class using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

The below script inserts an iframe to the class rightImage. The problem is there are multiple elements that use the rightImage class so the iframe is showing multiple times. How do I get it so it only add's it the last element that uses the rightImage class so therefore the iframe only appears once?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".rightImage").append("<iframe src='test.uk'></iframe>");  
   });
```

I have no control over the parent page so that's why I have to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)** selector:

> Selects the last matched element.

```
$(".rightImage:last").append("<iframe src='test.uk'></iframe>");
```

or **[.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)**:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the final one in the set.

```
$(".rightImage").last().append("<iframe src='test.uk'></iframe>");
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(".rightImage:last").append("<iframe src='test.uk'></iframe>");`

or

`$(".rightImage").last().append("<iframe src='test.uk'></iframe>");`

or

`$(".rightImage").eq(-1).append("<iframe src='test.uk'></iframe>");`

Answer (score 1):

Try [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) or [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the final one in the set.

```
$(".rightImage").last().append("<iframe src='test.uk'></iframe>");
```